# Confirm Contribution button not clickable for non-default payment processor

Tags: civicontribute, upgrade, payment-processor, iats

When selecting the non-default payment processor (ACH in this case), the "Confirm Contribution" becomes non-clickable (greyed out).  Switching back to the default (credit card) it is still unclickable until I refresh page.

This may be related to the following StackExchange question:
[Can someone help me fix a "greyed out" save button for a new contribution?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19867/can-someone-help-me-fix-a-greyed-out-save-button-for-a-new-contribution)

which made me originally think it was a URL inconsistency due to a recent upgrade from 4.6.x to 4.7.23

- All URLs and paths look consistent (I made them absolute) and caches have been cleared
- Rebuilding contribution page doesn't fix it
- Other sites running 4.7 and iATS don't exhibit this problem
- All payment methods work through the backend New Contribution page
- Non-default payment processor works when on its own contribution page

Running WP with iATS 1.6.0.

Comment: Thinking this might be a javascript issue, examining the browser error console, shows references to jquery files that don't exist /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css?r=BIVK6 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Missing jquery files due to old html snippet (fixed) but still have unclickable confirm button with non-default payment processor :/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are some outstanding 4.7 issues with non-default payment processors in CiviCRM; it's not related to iATS - it affects all payment processors; Here's one JIRA issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19508 - no resolution yet as there is a workaround;